# C++11 ABI: Possible to mix std::string and std::__cxx11::string in the same file?

Tags: c++, c++11, abi

It has become a nuisance to be forced to compile our whole software project with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` set to 0, just so that we can link to one closed-source library whose vendor insists on backward ABI compatibility without offering a version compiled with the C++11 ABI.

This forces us to recompile several other libraries that are readily available as system packages, just because the default mode of compilation of the whole system has switched to C++11 ABI as the default (specifically, rhel8 clones).

My question is thus, is it possible to mix the two ABIs in a single object file, by, for example, referring to the old string as `std::string` and the new string as `std::__cxx11::string` explicitly -- or through some aliases -- then copying the raw data from c++11-abi string into the old-abi string on the way into the problematic library, and then copying the raw string data from the old-abi string back into a c++11- abi string on the way back from the library?

To the best of my understanding of `libstdc++` source code, the `inline namespace __cxx11` is never declared if `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` is 0; and if it is 1, the old-abi `std::string` and `basic_string` etc. cannot be accessed in any way.

So far I've only been able to create a `const char *` wrapper for the old-abi library and use that wrapper from the c++11-abi library. It works:

```
$ nm --demangle a.out | ack ~basic_string
             U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
             U std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
```

But I find it **very** ugly. Is this the only way or is there something better?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html from here it seems that that you can mix them when linking, but each compile unit must use just one. Just my read of the text, I never worked with dual abi

Comment: I have tried for the past hour and can't make it work. From what I've read on the internet it seems it is not possible and this is by design: https://greek0.net/tag/c.html You either can recompile all sources and use C++11 string or you use the old string in all of your application.

Comment: I'd say it's time to consider putting more pressure on the vendor (if that is possible), looking for alternate libraries or create your own library.

Comment: a decade has passed since C++11. It's time to move to C++14, 17 or even 20

Comment: @phuclv It seems that you have stopped reading after "C++11" in the title. If you read further, you'll realize your comment makes no sense. We are using C++17, but it's completely irrelevant to this question so I didn't mention it.

Comment: @bolov: Oracle is notorious for not offering any real support to its clients, so my hopes are not high about pressuring them. (Oracle's `libocci.so` is the cause of this post -- it's still old-ABI compiled in Oracle version 21c with no new-ABI alternative). My attempts at combining the two `string`s in the same object were also fruitless, and gcc's #ifdef-ing based on `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` seems to turn off the other string *completely* in that object file. Multiple object files with different values for the macro still works to create an interface between them though.

Comment: @Irfy I've read everything before commenting. You didn't say anything about the standard you're using

Comment: @phuclv You are confusing C++ standard vs. C++ ABI. The question is about C++11 ABI which (as of 2021) is the latest C++ ABI and is (by default) used by compilers implementing C++ standards 11/14/17/20/23 -- that's why mentioning the standard is irrelevant in this question. You can read more about the ABI change here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html (I've edited the question title to include ABI in it to eliminate any further confusion)